# For very basic markdown, will these regular expressions work?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, code-injection

just a quick question about Regular expressions: Will this code work for any grooming I will need to do? (i.e. Can this be inputted into a database and be safe?)

```
function markdown2html($text) {
        $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    // Strong Emphasis
    $text = preg_replace('/__(.+?)__/s', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/s', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);

    // Underline
    $text = preg_replace('/_([^_]+)_/', '<p style="text-decoration: underline;">$1</p>', $text);
    //Italic
    $text = preg_replace('/\*([^\*]+)\*/', '<em>$1</em>', $text);

    // Windows to Unix
    $text = str_replace('\r\n', '\n', $text);
    // Macintosh to Unix
    $text = str_replace('\r', '\n', $text);

    //Paragraphs
    $text = '<p>' . str_replace("\n\n", '</p><p>', $text) . '</p>';
    $text = str_replace("\n", '<br />', $text);

    // [Linked Text](Url)   
   $text = preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)]\(([a-z0-9._~:\/?#@!$&\'()*+,;=%]+)\)/i', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $text);

   return $text;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just... try it

Comment: Works on test, just wondering if it would stop SQL injection.

Comment: Why do you think about injection? Did you use old and deprecated mysql lib?

Comment: @James this will have no impact on SQL injections. Be sure to use PDO if you want better protection.

Comment: I strongly recommend you put Markdown into your database and parse it on the way out. Then you can change your Markdown implementation. Besides — what if a user wants to edit their post?

Comment: How does anything your Markdown-to-HTML conversion have anything to do with SQL injection?  There is nothing related to SQL in your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely not.

Your code has nothing to do with SQL -- it does not modify `'` or `\` characters at all. Commingling the formatting functionality of this function with SQL escaping is silly.

Your code may also introduce HTML injection in some situations -- I'm particularly suspicious of the URL linking regex. Without a proper parser involved, I would not trust it an inch.

Answer (score 0):

No, the data can not assured to be safe after passing through that function.

You need to either escape sql-sensitive characters or use PDO/Mysqli. Preapared statements are much more handy anyway.

Don't use the old way of hacking together a query, ie:

```
$query = 'select * from table where col = '.$value;
```

You're just asking for trouble there.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things jumped out at me:

I believe that the first two regexs (`'/__(.+?)__/s'` and the corresponding one for `*`) handle ___word___ and ***word*** incorrectly –– they will treat the third character as part of the word, so you will get ***word*** (where the first * is bold and the trailing one is not) instead of ***word***.

On the third one (`'/_([^_]+)_/'`), is it really appropriate for

> do _not_ do that

to turn into

> do <p style="text-decoration: underline;">not</p> do that

?

Of course I’m ***not*** saying that it’s OK to use if you fix these issues.